# Kotlin: define a coroutine scope in App class

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Is it a good practice to declare a coroutine scope inside the `App` class instead of using a Globascope?

```
class App : Application() {

    val applicationJob = Job()

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: App
            private set

        lateinit var appDefaultScope: CoroutineScope
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this@App
        appDefaultScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + applicationJob)
    }

}
```

Here I defined a variable `appDefaultScope` and initialized it in the App's `onCreate`

So anywhere in my code I could always do:

```
App.appDefaultScope.launch {
   // some operations
}
```

The main difference with a GlobalScope that I see is that here I can always cancel the job and shut down all potentially stuck coroutines.

**Are there are better alternatives to this?**

The reason is that i have some `object` functions that use coroutines and are not called from an activity (then I cannot provide them with a scope defined inside the activity) but need a scope for their operations.
An example of such object function is a Log that writes on a local database that can be called almost everywhere in the App.

Comment: I like your approach as I also have some parts of my app not specifically tied to a particular ViewModel/Activity/Fragment. Don't forget to cancel the `applicationJob` in `onTerminate`.

Comment: @Seven onTerminate() is not called in the production device.